# Is there a way to get battery level using unix c program

Tags: c, unix

is there any way to create a daemon in unix that would monitor my battery level and notify me after the crtical level. and is there any way to identify a node that is joining and leaving a network using c

Comment: Maybe. But there isn't nearly enough information.

Comment: "Unix" is not specific enough in this context. What actual OS(s) do you mean?

Comment: Hmmm, continuously monitoring battery level *is* using up battery power.  Just something to think about...

Answer (score 1):

As a solution to both problems (and assuming by "unix" you mean "Linux"), you could look into using DBus: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus

I know Ubuntu has daemons running by default which trigger DBus events when network connections change and there are standard endpoints for things like current battery charge.

Look for information on DBus network manager and perhaps try this project for the power monitoring portion: http://powersave.sourceforge.net/powersave/DBus.html

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good start for you:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=367978

`acpi -b`

ACPI project: http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/acpi/

Answer (score 0):

Peeking into [apcupsd](http://www.apcupsd.com/) may be useful.